# Split Color SVG Line

Tags: css, html, svg, colors, path

I'm currently coding a design mockup into HTMl and I'm trying to figure out the best way to achieve this look responsively. As you see, there's a purple line that stems from the hero CTA button in the bottom right corner. How would I go about changing the line color when it enters the new section; purple to white?

I thought about making two separate lines, but It's difficult to always have them line up right. I wonder if there's some sort of masking trick?

I added a red circle to show the interlacing I'm having issues with.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flapM.png)

Comment: read about mix-blend-mode

Comment: Thanks for that! The only issue now is to get the line completely white. A blend mode sorta dulls it out.